# Why are my JSX HTML tags being broken across multiple lines in my editor?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx

[SOLVED]

My code goes from :
[image]

to this after saving:
[image]

See the code inside the return statement... It happens after doing a save... It's just so unreadable... What is causing it and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're in a `.js` file, so the automatic formatter VSC uses is for JavaScript, not JSX - it's choking on the `<`s because in JS, those are *operators*, not JSX tag delimiters.

Change the file name from `App.js` to `App.jsx` for the formatter to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there was a **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter** extension enabled which was causing all this. Disabling it solved the issue. Thanks Brian Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file to jsx instead of js. VS Code works fine with jsx files